# I am having trouble with this program. There is only 1 compiling error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, bitmap

I am having trouble adding with the function pyth.p_t. The error is on line 40. The line is adding 100 to function pyth.p_t. The user inputs the values so the function isn't determined.

**ConsolApplication3.cpp:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "main_to_pyth.h"

#include <direct.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "bitmap_image.hpp"

#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    float a, b, c;
    float x1, x2, x3;
    float y1, y2, y3;

    ifstream myfile;

    bitmap_image image("Pythagorean_Theorom.bmp");
    image_drawer draw(image);


    cout << "Enter a,b,c of pythagorean theorom and 0 \n for the value you want to find." << endl;
    cout << "Enter Value 'a' \n";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter Value 'b' \n";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Enter Value 'c' \n";
    cin >> c;
    pyth.p_t(a, b, c);
    //consol output
    if (a == 0) {
        cout << "a = " << pyth.p_t;

        float x1 = 200; //a
        float y1 = 100 + pyth.p_t; //a

        float x2 = 200 + b; //b
        float y2 = 100; //b

        float x3 = 200; //c
        float y3 = 100 - c; //c
    }
    else if (b == 0) {
        cout << "b = " << pyth.p_t;
    }
    else if (c == 0) {
        cout << "c = " << pyth.p_t;
    }
    else {
        cout << "You failed... i am disapointed";
    }
    //consol output

        draw.pen_color(255, 255, 255);
        draw.triangle( x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);

    image.save_image("Pythagorean_Theorom.bmp");

    myfile.open("Pythagorean_Theorom.bmp");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Pythagorean Theorom.cpp:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <math.h>
#include "main_to_pyth.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

    static float p_t(float a, float b, float c) {

        if (a == 0 && b != 0 && c != 0) {
            // 0 equals nothing for parameters
            //a
            float pyth_c = (pow(c, 2)) - (pow(b, 2));
            float pyth_a = sqrt(pyth_c);
            return pyth_a;
        }
        else if (a != 0 && b == 0 && c != 0) {
            //b
            float pyth_c_1 = (pow(c, 2)) - (pow(a, 2));
            float pyth_b_1 = sqrt(pyth_c_1);
            return pyth_b_1;
        }
        else if (a != 0 && b != 0 && c == 0) {
            //c
            float pyth_a_2 = (pow(a, 2)) - (pow(b, 2));
            float pyth_c_2 = sqrt(pyth_a_2);
            return pyth_c_2;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

**main_to_pyth.h:**

```
#pragma once

#ifndef MAIN_TO_PYTH_H
#define MAIN_TO_PYTH_H


struct pythagorean_theorom {
    const float inch = 5;

    static float p_t(float a, float b, float c);

}pyth;

#endif
```

**Consol:**

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication3, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>ConsoleApplication3.cpp
1>c:\users\lisa\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3.cpp(40): error C2297: '+': illegal, right operand has type 'float (__cdecl *)(float,float,float)'
1>c:\users\lisa\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3.cpp(60): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'float' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>Done building project "ConsoleApplication3.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: `pyth.p_t` is a function. Your assumption that you can call it once with arguments and then refer to the result without `(<arguments>)` is wrong. And you have not defined the `p_t` of `pythagorean_theorom`. You also don't need an instance of it and `inch` does not belong to the MCVE.

Comment: @ LogicStuff  
The errors now say "1>Pythagorean Theorom.obj : error LNK2005: "struct pythagorean_theorom pyth" (?pyth@@3Upythagorean_theorom@@A) already defined in ConsoleApplication3.obj" 1>ConsoleApplication3.obj : "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static float __cdecl pythagorean_theorom::p_t(float,float,float)" (?p_t@pythagorean_theorom@@SAMMMM@Z) referenced in function _main"

Comment: New error means linker cannot find definition of function `static float pythagorean_theorom::p_t(float,float,float)`, this because in source file you are defining function `static float p_t(float,float,float)`. You probably want to change signature (unless you also need non-struct version of that function)

Answer (score 0):

edit:
Still not really sure what you are trying to do.
First of all, as noted by the other person's comment, you need to define the function somewhere.  Right now it is floating off in space.  Use the scope resolution operator `::`.

```
pythagorean_theorom::p_t(a, b, c);
```

...

```
struct pythagorean_theorom {
const float inch = 5;

static float p_t(float a, float b, float c);
```

};

...

```
float pythagorean_theorom::p_t(float a, float b, float c) {
```

...

Here is main with the graphics stuff removed, guessing at what you want:

```
int main() {
float a, b, c;
float x1, x2, x3;
float y1, y2, y3;


cout << "Enter a,b,c of pythagorean theorom and 0 \n for the value you want to find." << endl;
cout << "Enter Value 'a' \n";
cin >> a;
cout << "Enter Value 'b' \n";
cin >> b;
cout << "Enter Value 'c' \n";
cin >> c;

float foundvalue = pythagorean_theorom::p_t(a, b, c);
//consol output
if (a == 0) {
    cout << "a = " << foundvalue;

    float x1 = 200; //a
    float y1 = 100 + a; //a

    float x2 = 200 + b; //b
    float y2 = 100; //b

    float x3 = 200; //c
    float y3 = 100 - c; //c
}
else if (b == 0) {
    cout << "b = " << foundvalue;
}
else if (c == 0) {
    cout << "c = " << foundvalue;
}
else {
    cout << "You failed... i am disapointed";
}

return 0;
```

}

---

Looks like you are trying to return a function, which is illegal here.

You need to call the function, using the `()` operator.

e.g. `pyth.p_t(a,b,c);`

also, don't you want a^2 + b^2 = c^2 ?
You would need to change the third else if in your Pythagoream Theorem.cpp to be

```
float pyth_a_2 = (pow(a,2)) + (pow(b,2));
```

Comment: The errors now say        "1>Pythagorean Theorom.obj : error LNK2005: "struct pythagorean_theorom pyth" (?pyth@@3Upythagorean_theorom@@A) already defined in ConsoleApplication3.obj"
1>ConsoleApplication3.obj :      "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static float __cdecl pythagorean_theorom::p_t(float,float,float)" (?p_t@pythagorean_theorom@@SAMMMM@Z) referenced in function _main"